# Regular Expression for Any String that Doesn't End in .asp

Tags: regex, iis, asp-classic

I'm (unfortunately) using IIS and I am doing a rewrite that creates friendly profile URLs.  I have come up with a workable solution but would like to allow for periods in the usernames.  So, the rewritten URL format is `profile/username` but I obviously don't want to redirect any path containing **.asp** so scripts don't get rerouted.  The actual URL they are masking is `profile/iviator.asp?p=username`.  Simple enough, right?  Yeah, well, the regex engine IIS' rewrite module relies on is bogus.

Comment: What exacly is bogus in the regex engine?

Comment: Microsoft can help. Write the non-bogus pattern / rule and see here http://goo.gl/XwpvV

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** After some research I have now found out that IIS doesn't use the .NET regex engine but the one in the VC++ runtime, which doesn't seem to allow for negative lookbehinds.

You can, however, add conditions to your patterns which should suit your problem just fine (learned from [this post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1175965.aspx)). Something like this may do the trick:

```
<rule name="RewriteNonAsp" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*?\.asp(?:\?|$)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="<path>" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: @GabrielRyanNahmias, edited. Note that regexpal doesn't use the same regex engine though.